# disabled="disabled" not working for anchor button : JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In my JQuery mobile application, I have an anchor button. It should be disabled at first and on checking the check box, able the anchor button. But it is not working.

Html code is

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" class="custom" />
<div id="check">
 <a data-role="button" data-transition="fade" data-theme="c" disabled="disabled" onclick="PostRegistration()" class="forcolouredbuttontext">
    REGISTER
 </a>
</div>
```

Script is

```
    $('#check').ready(function(){
            $('#checkbox2').click(function() {
                var buttonsChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked');
                if (buttonsChecked.length) {            
                    $('div#check a').button('enable');              
                } 
                else {              
                    $('div#check a').button('disable');             
                }
            });
        });
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Please help,

Thanks

Comment: parameter "disabled" used only for "form"s tags, like "input", "textarea", etc

Comment: change 'a' on 'input type="button"'

Comment: are you change your script? $('div#check a') to $('div#check input')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disabled="disabled"` is used for input controls. You cannot disable the anchor tag.

Try using a button element instead..

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" class="custom" />
<div id="check">
 <input type="button" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" data-theme="c" disabled="disabled" onclick="PostRegistration()" class="forcolouredbuttontext" value="REGISTER" />
</div>
```

//

```
$('#check').ready(function(){
            $('#checkbox2').click(function() {
                var buttonsChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked');
                if (buttonsChecked.length) {            
                    $('div#check input[type=button]').attr('disabled', false);              
                } 
                else {              
                    $('div#check input[type=button]').attr('disabled', true);              
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: Is there any way to disable able anchor button?

Comment: No .. The only thing you can do is e.preventDefault() on the anchor tag which will return false and prevent the default action

Answer (score 0):

```
<a data-role="button" data-transition="fade" data-theme="c" disabled="disabled" onclick="PostRegistration()" class="forcolouredbuttontext" id="checkbox2">
```